# Set up Eclipse with MinGW

Tags: c++, eclipse, mingw, std

I am having trouble getting Eclipse Luna to work with the MinGW compiler. I know this shouldn't be difficult, but I cannot get it to work for some reason.

I installed Eclipse. I then installed MinGW to the default directory. I installed both the MinGW base and the g++ compiler. I then restarted eclipse. Eclipse launched successfully, but my C++ programs won't compile. It says "symbol 'std' could not be resolved".

Its hard to explain what I'm confused on, because I have no idea what I could be doing wrong. So, here's a video of what I did when installing it. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=59cu2SRKWzs
What did I do wrong?

The code I entered was

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Add the code you tried, it will be easier for others to answer!

Comment: Does it compile and link successfully? Can you run the produced binary?

Comment: It will not compile.